Settled funds are always used first right?
In my IRA or Roth IRA account lets say I sell a stock. Then either the same day or the next day, I want to buy the same stock or another stock. Assume that in my account I have enough settled money to pay for the second purchase entirely. I can do this and T+2 rule will not prevent me here right? I mean, I want to confirm that, as a general rule, first my settled funds are always used to purchase stocks correct?

Suppose you own stock ABC and you have $10k of settled cash in your account.  You decide to buy $10k of stock XYZ.  No problem, the trade goes through.
Now suppose in addition to the above, you decide to sell stock ABC first.  T+2 settlement for this trade does not affect the above in any way.

I don't think it matters.
Since this is T+2, your funds used for purchase should only leave your account two trade days after the date on which the order is fulfilled. By that time, your sales proceeds should have become available.
